# page width long table

Tags: tables, luatex, xtable

Is there a better way to set this long table? something better than `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6cm}`? many thanks in advance.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{footnotesize}
    \begin{longtable} 
        {l >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6cm}cccc}
        \caption{Papers are used for bibliometric analysis}
        \label{tab:xbigg}
        \\
        \toprule
        & 1st Author, Year, Journal & Title & TLC & TLC/t & TGC & TGC/t \\
        \toprule
        \endfirsthead
        %\caption[]{Financial }\\
        % \multicolumn{5}{c}%
        % {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
        \toprule
        & 1st Author, Year, Journal & Title & TLC & TLC/t & TGC & TGC/t \\
        \toprule
        \endhead
        \bottomrule 
        %\multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule 
        \endlastfoot
        1 & Abadi F, 2016, Int J Emerg Mark & The Impact Of Banking Concentration On Firm Leverage In Emerging Markets &   0 & 0.00 &   3 & 0.60 \\ 
        2 & Abdallah Ah, 2019, Agric Finance Rev & Impact Of Agricultural Credit On Farm Income Under The Savanna And Transitional Zones Of Ghana &   0 & 0.00 &   5 & 2.50 \\ 
        3 & Abdul-Salam Y, 2019, World Dev & Modelling The Impact Of Market Imperfections On Farm Household Investment In Stand-Alone Solar Pv Systems &   0 & 0.00 &   3 & 1.50 \\ 
        4 & Abdullah S, 2016, Appl Econ & Do Women Borrowers Augment Financial Performance Of Mfis? &   0 & 0.00 &  13 & 2.60 \\ 
        5 & Abor Jy, 2018, J Afr Bus & Mobile Telephony, Financial Inclusion And Inclusive Growth &   0 & 0.00 &  20 & 6.67 \\ 
        6 & Abubakar Ha, 2015, World J Entrep Manag & Entrepreneurship Development And Financial Literacy In Africa &   0 & 0.00 &   4 & 0.67 \\ 
        7 & Abubakar Ya, 2019, Technovation & What Specific Modes Of Internationalization Influence Sme Innovation In Sub-Saharan Least Developed Countries (Ldcs)? &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.50 \\ 
        8 & Adegbite Oo, 2020, World Dev & Bridging The Financial Inclusion Gender Gap In Smallholder Agriculture In Nigeria: An Untapped Potential For Sustainable Development &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        9 & Adesua-Lincoln A, 2011, Afr J Bus Manage & Assessing Nigerian Female Entrepreneur's Access To Finance For Business Start-Up And Growth &   1 & 0.10 &   5 & 0.50 \\ 
        10 & Adomako S, 2016, Ventur Cap & The Moderating Influence Of Financial Literacy On The Relationship Between Access To Finance And Firm Growth In Ghana &   2 & 0.40 &  14 & 2.80 \\ 
        11 & Agbodji Ae, 2015, Int J Soc Econ & Gender Inequality In Multidimensional Welfare Deprivation In West Africa The Case Of Burkina Faso And Togo &   0 & 0.00 &   3 & 0.50 \\ 
        12 & Ahmad Sz, 2015, Equal Divers Incl & Strengthening Access To Finance For Women-Owned Smes In Developing Countries &   0 & 0.00 &   8 & 1.33 \\ 
        13 & Ahn S, 2009, J Bank Financ & The Role Of Bank Monitoring In Corporate Governance: Evidence From Borrowers' Earnings Management Behavior &   1 & 0.08 &  59 & 4.92 \\ 
        14 & Aivazian Va, 2015, J Financ Intermed & Bank Loan Contracting And Corporate Diversification: Does Organizational Structure Matter To Lenders? &   0 & 0.00 &   5 & 0.83 \\ 
        15 & Ajefu Jb, 2019, Oxf Dev Stud & Migrant Remittances And Financial Inclusion Among Households In Nigeria &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        16 & Albuquerque R, 2004, Rev Econ Stud & Optimal Lending Contracts And Firm Dynamics &   1 & 0.06 & 154 & 9.06 \\ 
        17 & Alden L, 2016, Kyklos & Discrimination In The Credit Market? Access To Financial Capital Among Self-Employed Immigrants &   1 & 0.20 &  13 & 2.60 \\ 
        18 & Alesina Af, 2013, J Eur Econ Assoc & Do Women Pay More For Credit? Evidence From Italy &  15 & 1.88 &  63 & 7.88 \\ 
        19 & Ali Aees, 2017, Int J Soc Econ & The Challenges Facing Poverty Alleviation And Financial Inclusion In North-East Kenya Province (Nekp) &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        20 & Allen F, 2016, J Financ Intermed & The Foundations Of Financial Inclusion: Understanding Ownership And Use Of Formal Accounts &  11 & 2.20 &  59 & 11.80 \\ 
        21 & Allon F, 2014, Aust Feminist Stud & The Feminisation Of Finance Gender, Labour And The Limits Of Inclusion &   0 & 0.00 &  27 & 3.86 \\ 
        22 & Andries Am, 2018, Sustainability-Basel & Financial Infrastructure And Access To Finance For European Smes &   0 & 0.00 &   3 & 1.00 \\ 
        23 & Angori G, 2019, Appl Econ & Lending Technologies, Banking Relationships, And Firms' Access To Credit In Italy: The Role Of Firm Size &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        24 & Aristei D, 2016, Financ Res Lett & Does Gender Matter For Firms' Access To Credit? Evidence From International Data &   3 & 0.60 &  11 & 2.20 \\ 
        25 & Asiedu E, 2012, Am Econ Rev & Access To Credit By Small Businesses: How Relevant Are Race, Ethnicity, And Gender? &  11 & 1.22 &  28 & 3.11 \\ 
        26 & Asiedu E, 2013, Am Econ Rev & Access To Credit By Firms In Sub-Saharan Africa: How Relevant Is Gender? &  11 & 1.38 &  28 & 3.50 \\ 
        27 & Asuming Po, 2019, J Afr Bus & Financial Inclusion In Sub-Saharan Africa: Recent Trends And Determinants &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.50 \\ 
        28 & Aterido R, 2013, World Dev & Access To Finance In Sub-Saharan Africa: Is There A Gender Gap? &  16 & 2.00 &  54 & 6.75 \\ 
        29 & Balogun O, 2018, Acta Structilia & Evaluating Credit Accessibility Predictors Among Small And Medium Contractors In The South African Construction Industry &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        30 & Balogun Oa, 2016, Procedia Engineer & Determinants Predicting Credit Accessibility Within Small And Medium-Sized Enterprises In The South African Construction Industry &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        31 & Bates T, 2000, Econ Dev Q & Financing The Development Of Urban Minority Communities: Lessons Of History &   1 & 0.05 &  26 & 1.24 \\ 
        32 & Bates T, 2016, Econ Dev Q & Impacts Of Owner Race And Geographic Context On Access To Small-Business Financing &   1 & 0.20 &   9 & 1.80 \\ 
        33 & Baydas Mm, 1994, World Dev & Discrimination Against Women In Formal Credit Markets - Reality Or Rhetoric &   6 & 0.22 &  17 & 0.63 \\ 
        34 & Baye Fm, 2013, Afr Dev Rev & Household Economic Well-Being: Response To Micro-Credit Access In Cameroon &   0 & 0.00 &   4 & 0.50 \\ 
        35 & Beck T, 2008, World Bank Econ Rev & Access To Finance: An Unfinished Agenda &  13 & 1.00 &  81 & 6.23 \\ 
        36 & Bedane B, 2016, Econ Bull & Determinants Of Credit Rationing In Ethiopia: Firm-Level Evidence &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.20 \\ 
        37 & Belas J, 2016, Econ Sociol & Microenterprises And Significant Risk Factors In Loan Process &   0 & 0.00 &  23 & 4.60 \\ 
        38 & Berger An, 2014, J Bank Financ & Do Small Businesses Still Prefer Community Banks? &   1 & 0.14 &  35 & 5.00 \\ 
        39 & Biggs T, 2002, J Econ Behav Organ & Ethnic Networks And Access To Credit: Evidence From The Manufacturing Sector In Kenya &   5 & 0.26 &  35 & 1.84 \\ 
        40 & Bigsten A, 2006, World Bank Res Obser & What Have We Learned From A Decade Of Manufacturing Enterprise Surveys In Africa? &   2 & 0.13 &  65 & 4.33 \\ 
        41 & Blanchflower Dg, 2003, Rev Econ Stat & Discrimination In The Small-Business Credit Market &  29 & 1.61 & 224 & 12.44 \\ 
        42 & Blau Bm, 2017, Public Choice & Lobbying, Political Connections And Emergency Lending By The Federal Reserve &   0 & 0.00 &   4 & 1.00 \\ 
        43 & Bongomin Goc, 2017, Cogent Econ Financ & Financial Intermediation And Financial Inclusion Of Poor Households: Mediating Role Of Social Networks In Rural Uganda &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.25 \\ 
        44 & Bongomin Goc, 2018, Afr J Econ Manag Stu & Social Network: Testing The Predictive Power Of Its Dimensions In Explaining Financial Inclusion Of The Poor In Rural Uganda &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        45 & Boohene R, 2018, J Enterp Cult & Entrepreneur's Social Capital And Firm Growth: The Moderating Role Of Access To Finance &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.33 \\ 
        46 & Boubakri N, 2016, J Corp Financ & Culture And Externally Financed Firm Growth &   0 & 0.00 &  24 & 4.80 \\ 
        47 & Brana S, 2013, Small Bus Econ & Microcredit: An Answer To The Gender Problem In Funding? &   2 & 0.25 &  26 & 3.25 \\ 
        48 & Braun M, 2019, J Bus Res & Interlocking Directorates, Access To Credit, And Business Performance In Chile During Early Industrialization &   0 & 0.00 &   3 & 1.50 \\ 
        49 & Brett Ja, 2006, Hum Organ & "We Sacrifice And Eat Less ": The Structural Complexities Of Microinance Participation &   0 & 0.00 &  53 & 3.53 \\ 
        50 & Bruder J, 2011, Int J Entrep Behav R & Financial Constraints Of Ethnic Entrepreneurship: Evidence From Germany &   2 & 0.20 &  19 & 1.90 \\ 
        51 & Buttner Eh, 1988, J Bus Venturing & Bank Loan Officers Perceptions Of The Characteristics Of Men, Women, And Successful Entrepreneurs &   9 & 0.27 & 103 & 3.12 \\ 
        52 & Cabeza-Garcia L, 2019, Women Stud Int Forum & Female Financial Inclusion And Its Impacts On Inclusive Economic Development &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        53 & Calcagnini G, 2015, Ital Econ J & Gender Differences In Bank Loan Access: An Empirical Analysis &   0 & 0.00 &   5 & 0.83 \\ 
        54 & Campello M, 2012, Rev Financ & Access To Liquidity And Corporate Investment In Europe During The Financial Crisis &   0 & 0.00 &  37 & 4.11 \\ 
        55 & Canton E, 2013, Small Bus Econ & Perceived Credit Constraints In The European Union &   4 & 0.50 &  32 & 4.00 \\ 
        56 & Cao Ntk, 2019, Asian Econ J & What Factors Determine Whether Small And Medium Enterprises Obtain Credit From The Formal Credit Market? The Case Of Vietnam &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        57 & Carter S, 2015, Int Small Bus J & Barriers To Ethnic Minority And Women's Enterprise: Existing Evidence, Policy Tensions And Unsettled Questions &   0 & 0.00 &  64 & 10.67 \\ 
        58 & Cesaroni Fm, 2015, Proc Eur Conf Entrep & Access To Bank Credit During The Economic Crisis: A Comparison Between Italian Male And Female Entrepreneurs &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        59 & Chai Sj, 2019, Asia Pac J Manag & Social Networks And Informal Financial Inclusion In China &   1 & 0.50 &   2 & 1.00 \\ 
        60 & Chakravarty Sr, 2013, J Policy Model & Financial Inclusion In India: An Axiomatic Approach &   4 & 0.50 &  30 & 3.75 \\ 
        61 & Chandio Aa, 2017, Cogent Econ Financ & Famers' Access To Credit: Does Collateral Matter Or Cash Flow Matter?Evidence From Sindh, Pakistan &   2 & 0.50 &   9 & 2.25 \\ 
        62 & Chaudhuri K, 2012, Appl Econ & Credit Rationing In Rural Credit Markets Of India &   3 & 0.33 &   8 & 0.89 \\ 
        63 & Chauvet L, 2017, World Dev & Financial Inclusion, Bank Concentration, And Firm Performance &   1 & 0.25 &  14 & 3.50 \\ 
        64 & Chavan Al, 2009, Lect Notes Comput Sc & How Mobile Money Can Drive Financial Inclusion For Women At The Bottom Of The Pyramid (Bop) In Indian Urban Centers &   0 & 0.00 &   5 & 0.42 \\ 
        65 & Chen Dq, 2016, Abacus & Social Trust And Bank Loan Financing: Evidence From China &   0 & 0.00 &  11 & 2.20 \\ 
        66 & Chen Dy, 2017, Electron Commer Res & Gender Discrimination In Online Peer-To-Peer Credit Lending: Evidence From A Lending Platform In China &   0 & 0.00 &   9 & 2.25 \\ 
        67 & Chen Hk, 2018, J Financ Stabil & The Effect Of The Political Connections Of Government Bank Ceos On Bank Performance During The Financial Crisis &   0 & 0.00 &   6 & 2.00 \\ 
        68 & Chen Lh, 2008, Proceedings Of The 3rd International Conference On Product Innovation Management, Vols I And Ii & Study On Reasons For Internal Financing Preference Of Family Business In China &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        69 & Chen Yl, 2013, J Bank Financ & Greasing The Wheels Of Bank Lending: Evidence From Private Firms In China &   2 & 0.25 &  46 & 5.75 \\ 
        70 & Chen Ys, 2014, J Financ Serv Res & The Benefits Of Political Connection: Evidence From Individual Bank-Loan Contracts &   3 & 0.43 &  26 & 3.71 \\ 
        71 & Chen Zb, 2017, J Fam Econ Iss & Financial Inclusion In China: Use Of Credit &   1 & 0.25 &   2 & 0.50 \\ 
        72 & Cheng Ej, 2014, China Agr Econ Rev & The Demand For Credit, Credit Rationing And The Role Of Microfinance Evidence From Poor Rural Counties Of China &   1 & 0.14 &   7 & 1.00 \\ 
        73 & Chipfupa U, 2018, Agrekon & Explaining Smallholder Aspirations To Expand Irrigation Crop Production In Makhathini And Ndumo-B, Kwazulu-Natal, South Africa &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.33 \\ 
        74 & Chu Lk, 2019, Econ Bull & Determinants Of Financial Inclusions: Comparing High, Middle, And Low-Income Countries &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        75 & Churchill Sa, 2020, Appl Econ & Financial Inclusion And Poverty: A Tale Of Forty-Five Thousand Households &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 1.00 \\ 
        76 & Claessens S, 2008, J Financ Econ & Political Connections And Preferential Access To Finance: The Role Of Campaign Contributions &  25 & 1.92 & 442 & 34.00 \\ 
        77 & Cloud C, 1993, Rev Black Polit Econ & What Do We Know About Racial-Discrimination In Mortgage Markets &   0 & 0.00 &  17 & 0.61 \\ 
        78 & Coleman S, 2000, J Small Bus Manage & Access To Capital And Terms Of Credit: A Comparison Of Men- And Women-Owned Small Businesses &  22 & 1.05 & 201 & 9.57 \\ 
        79 & Cornaggia J, 2013, J Financ Econ & Does Risk Management Matter? Evidence From The Us Agricultural Industry &   0 & 0.00 &  23 & 2.88 \\ 
        80 & Cornille D, 2019, J Financ Stabil & Heterogeneous Effects Of Credit Constraints On Smes' Employment: Evidence From The European Sovereign Debt Crisis &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.50 \\ 
        81 & Corrado G, 2015, J Econ Geogr & The Geography Of Financial Inclusion Across Europe During The Global Crisis &   1 & 0.17 &  12 & 2.00 \\ 
        82 & Corsi M, 2017, J Dev Stud & Gender Discrimination In Microfinance? Some Evidence From Uganda &   1 & 0.25 &   3 & 0.75 \\ 
        83 & Cui Yj, 2017, J Interdiscip Math & Analysis On Determinants Of Rural Household Credit In China &   2 & 0.50 &   2 & 0.50 \\ 
        84 & Cull R, 2015, J Corp Financ & Government Connections And Financial Constraints: Evidence From A Large Representative Sample Of Chinese Firms &   4 & 0.67 &  83 & 13.83 \\ 
        85 & Cull R, 2019, Oxford B Econ Stat & Dual Credit Markets And Household Usage To Finance: Evidence From A Representative Chinese Household Survey &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        86 & Dadzie Kq, 2013, J Public Policy Mark & Inclusive Economic Development Programs And Consumers' Access To Credit In Emerging Market Economies: The Public Policy Role Of Marketing In Rural Bank Programs In Ghana &   0 & 0.00 &  18 & 2.25 \\ 
        87 & Dang Hd, 2020, Agric Finance Rev & Determinants Of Credit Demand Of Farmers In Lam Dong, Vietnam A Comparison Of Machine Learning And Multinomial Logit &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        88 & Das T, 2019, Int J Soc Econ & Does Credit Access Lead To Expansion Of Income And Multidimensional Poverty? A Study Of Rural Assam &   1 & 0.50 &   3 & 1.50 \\ 
        89 & Davutyan N, 2016, Emerg Mark Financ Tr & Determinants Of Saving-Borrowing Decisions And Financial Inclusion In A High Middle Income Country: The Turkish Case &   0 & 0.00 &   4 & 0.80 \\ 
        90 & Dawood Tc, 2019, Econ Sociol & Does Financial Inclusion Alleviate Household Poverty? Empirical Evidence From Indonesia &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        91 & Dehingia N, 2019, Ssm-Popul Hlth & More Than Credit: Exploring Associations Between Microcredit Programs And Maternal And Reproductive Health Service Utilization In India &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        92 & Dennis Sa, 2005, J Bus Finan Account & Firm Size Dependence In The Determinants Of Bank Term Loan Maturity &   1 & 0.06 &  14 & 0.88 \\ 
        93 & Desai Rm, 2011, Q J Polit Sci & The Costs Of Political Influence: Firm-Level Evidence From Developing Countries &   2 & 0.20 &  22 & 2.20 \\ 
        94 & Digiuseppe M, 2016, Econ Polit-Oxford & Borrowed Time: Sovereign Finance, Regime Type, And Leader Survival &   0 & 0.00 &   9 & 1.80 \\ 
        95 & Diniz E, 2012, Electron Commer R A & Triggers And Barriers To Financial Inclusion: The Use Of Ict-Based Branchless Banking In An Amazon County &   1 & 0.11 &  31 & 3.44 \\ 
        96 & Distinguin I, 2016, World Dev & Can Informal Firms Hurt Registered Smes' Access To Credit? &   0 & 0.00 &  16 & 3.20 \\ 
        97 & Domeher D, 2017, Int J Soc Econ & Micro Determinants Of The Extent Of Credit Rationing Amongst Smes In Ghana &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        98 & Domeher D, 2017, J Afr Bus & Inter-Sectoral Differences In The Sme Financing Gap: Evidence From Selected Sectors In Ghana &   0 & 0.00 &   9 & 2.25 \\ 
        99 & Doss Cr, 2019, Fem Econ & Gendered Paths To Asset Accumulation? Markets, Savings, And Credit In Developing Countries &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
        100 & Dossa Lh, 2008, Agr Hum Values & Socio-Economic Determinants Of Keeping Goats And Sheep By Rural People In Southern Benin &   0 & 0.00 &  14 & 1.08 \\ 
 
    \end{longtable}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case seems to be better option to use `xltabular` instead of `longtable` table. Beside this it is sensible for last four columns to use `S` columns defined in `siunitx` package:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} r
                   >{\raggedright}p{3cm}
                                  R
                                  c
                                  S[table-format=1.2]
                                  S[table-format=2.0]
                                  S[table-format=1.2]
                               @{}}
\caption{Papers are used for bibliometric analysis}
\label{tab:xbigg}               \\
    \toprule
    & 1st Author, Year, Journal & Title & TLC & {TLC/t} & {TGC} & {TGC/t} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Financial (cont.)}   \\
    \toprule
    & 1st Author, Year, Journal & Title & TLC & {TLC/t} & {TGC} & {TGC/t} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
    \multicolumn{7}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
1 & Abadi F, 2016, Int J Emerg Mark & The Impact Of Banking Concentration On Firm Leverage In Emerging Markets &   0 & 0.00 &   3 & 0.60 \\
2 & Abdallah Ah, 2019, Agric Finance Rev & Impact Of Agricultural Credit On Farm Income Under The Savanna And Transitional Zones Of Ghana &   0 & 0.00 &   5 & 2.50 \\
3 & Abdul-Salam Y, 2019, World Dev & Modelling The Impact Of Market Imperfections On Farm Household Investment In Stand-Alone Solar Pv Systems &   0 & 0.00 &   3 & 1.50 \\
4 & Abdullah S, 2016, Appl Econ & Do Women Borrowers Augment Financial Performance Of Mfis? &   0 & 0.00 &  13 & 2.60 \\
5 & Abor Jy, 2018, J Afr Bus & Mobile Telephony, Financial Inclusion And Inclusive Growth &   0 & 0.00 &  20 & 6.67 \\
6 & Abubakar Ha, 2015, World J Entrep Manag & Entrepreneurship Development And Financial Literacy In Africa &   0 & 0.00 &   4 & 0.67 \\
7 & Abubakar Ya, 2019, Technovation & What Specific Modes Of Internationalization Influence Sme Innovation In Sub-Saharan Least Developed Countries (Ldcs)? &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.50 \\
8 & Adegbite Oo, 2020, World Dev & Bridging The Financial Inclusion Gender Gap In Smallholder Agriculture In Nigeria: An Untapped Potential For Sustainable Development &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
9 & Adesua-Lincoln A, 2011, Afr J Bus Manage & Assessing Nigerian Female Entrepreneur's Access To Finance For Business Start-Up And Growth &   1 & 0.10 &   5 & 0.50 \\
10 & Adomako S, 2016, Ventur Cap & The Moderating Influence Of Financial Literacy On The Relationship Between Access To Finance And Firm Growth In Ghana &   2 & 0.40 &  14 & 2.80 \\
11 & Agbodji Ae, 2015, Int J Soc Econ & Gender Inequality In Multidimensional Welfare Deprivation In West Africa The Case Of Burkina Faso And Togo &   0 & 0.00 &   3 & 0.50 \\
12 & Ahmad Sz, 2015, Equal Divers Incl & Strengthening Access To Finance For Women-Owned Smes In Developing Countries &   0 & 0.00 &   8 & 1.33 \\
13 & Ahn S, 2009, J Bank Financ & The Role Of Bank Monitoring In Corporate Governance: Evidence From Borrowers' Earnings Management Behavior &   1 & 0.08 &  59 & 4.92 \\
14 & Aivazian Va, 2015, J Financ Intermed & Bank Loan Contracting And Corporate Diversification: Does Organizational Structure Matter To Lenders? &   0 & 0.00 &   5 & 0.83 \\
15 & Ajefu Jb, 2019, Oxf Dev Stud & Migrant Remittances And Financial Inclusion Among Households In Nigeria &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
16 & Albuquerque R, 2004, Rev Econ Stud & Optimal Lending Contracts And Firm Dynamics &   1 & 0.06 & 154 & 9.06 \\
17 & Alden L, 2016, Kyklos & Discrimination In The Credit Market? Access To Financial Capital Among Self-Employed Immigrants &   1 & 0.20 &  13 & 2.60 \\
18 & Alesina Af, 2013, J Eur Econ Assoc & Do Women Pay More For Credit? Evidence From Italy &  15 & 1.88 &  63 & 7.88 \\
19 & Ali Aees, 2017, Int J Soc Econ & The Challenges Facing Poverty Alleviation And Financial Inclusion In North-East Kenya Province (Nekp) &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
20 & Allen F, 2016, J Financ Intermed & The Foundations Of Financial Inclusion: Understanding Ownership And Use Of Formal Accounts &  11 & 2.20 &  59 & 11.80 \\
21 & Allon F, 2014, Aust Feminist Stud & The Feminisation Of Finance Gender, Labour And The Limits Of Inclusion &   0 & 0.00 &  27 & 3.86 \\
22 & Andries Am, 2018, Sustainability-Basel & Financial Infrastructure And Access To Finance For European Smes &   0 & 0.00 &   3 & 1.00 \\
23 & Angori G, 2019, Appl Econ & Lending Technologies, Banking Relationships, And Firms' Access To Credit In Italy: The Role Of Firm Size &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
24 & Aristei D, 2016, Financ Res Lett & Does Gender Matter For Firms' Access To Credit? Evidence From International Data &   3 & 0.60 &  11 & 2.20 \\
25 & Asiedu E, 2012, Am Econ Rev & Access To Credit By Small Businesses: How Relevant Are Race, Ethnicity, And Gender? &  11 & 1.22 &  28 & 3.11 \\
26 & Asiedu E, 2013, Am Econ Rev & Access To Credit By Firms In Sub-Saharan Africa: How Relevant Is Gender? &  11 & 1.38 &  28 & 3.50 \\
27 & Asuming Po, 2019, J Afr Bus & Financial Inclusion In Sub-Saharan Africa: Recent Trends And Determinants &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.50 \\
28 & Aterido R, 2013, World Dev & Access To Finance In Sub-Saharan Africa: Is There A Gender Gap? &  16 & 2.00 &  54 & 6.75 \\
29 & Balogun O, 2018, Acta Structilia & Evaluating Credit Accessibility Predictors Among Small And Medium Contractors In The South African Construction Industry &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
30 & Balogun Oa, 2016, Procedia Engineer & Determinants Predicting Credit Accessibility Within Small And Medium-Sized Enterprises In The South African Construction Industry &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
31 & Bates T, 2000, Econ Dev Q & Financing The Development Of Urban Minority Communities: Lessons Of History &   1 & 0.05 &  26 & 1.24 \\
32 & Bates T, 2016, Econ Dev Q & Impacts Of Owner Race And Geographic Context On Access To Small-Business Financing &   1 & 0.20 &   9 & 1.80 \\
33 & Baydas Mm, 1994, World Dev & Discrimination Against Women In Formal Credit Markets - Reality Or Rhetoric &   6 & 0.22 &  17 & 0.63 \\
34 & Baye Fm, 2013, Afr Dev Rev & Household Economic Well-Being: Response To Micro-Credit Access In Cameroon &   0 & 0.00 &   4 & 0.50 \\
35 & Beck T, 2008, World Bank Econ Rev & Access To Finance: An Unfinished Agenda &  13 & 1.00 &  81 & 6.23 \\
36 & Bedane B, 2016, Econ Bull & Determinants Of Credit Rationing In Ethiopia: Firm-Level Evidence &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.20 \\
37 & Belas J, 2016, Econ Sociol & Microenterprises And Significant Risk Factors In Loan Process &   0 & 0.00 &  23 & 4.60 \\
38 & Berger An, 2014, J Bank Financ & Do Small Businesses Still Prefer Community Banks? &   1 & 0.14 &  35 & 5.00 \\
39 & Biggs T, 2002, J Econ Behav Organ & Ethnic Networks And Access To Credit: Evidence From The Manufacturing Sector In Kenya &   5 & 0.26 &  35 & 1.84 \\
40 & Bigsten A, 2006, World Bank Res Obser & What Have We Learned From A Decade Of Manufacturing Enterprise Surveys In Africa? &   2 & 0.13 &  65 & 4.33 \\
41 & Blanchflower Dg, 2003, Rev Econ Stat & Discrimination In The Small-Business Credit Market &  29 & 1.61 & 224 & 12.44 \\
42 & Blau Bm, 2017, Public Choice & Lobbying, Political Connections And Emergency Lending By The Federal Reserve &   0 & 0.00 &   4 & 1.00 \\
43 & Bongomin Goc, 2017, Cogent Econ Financ & Financial Intermediation And Financial Inclusion Of Poor Households: Mediating Role Of Social Networks In Rural Uganda &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.25 \\
44 & Bongomin Goc, 2018, Afr J Econ Manag Stu & Social Network: Testing The Predictive Power Of Its Dimensions In Explaining Financial Inclusion Of The Poor In Rural Uganda &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
45 & Boohene R, 2018, J Enterp Cult & Entrepreneur's Social Capital And Firm Growth: The Moderating Role Of Access To Finance &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.33 \\
46 & Boubakri N, 2016, J Corp Financ & Culture And Externally Financed Firm Growth &   0 & 0.00 &  24 & 4.80 \\
47 & Brana S, 2013, Small Bus Econ & Microcredit: An Answer To The Gender Problem In Funding? &   2 & 0.25 &  26 & 3.25 \\
48 & Braun M, 2019, J Bus Res & Interlocking Directorates, Access To Credit, And Business Performance In Chile During Early Industrialization &   0 & 0.00 &   3 & 1.50 \\
49 & Brett Ja, 2006, Hum Organ & "We Sacrifice And Eat Less ": The Structural Complexities Of Microinance Participation &   0 & 0.00 &  53 & 3.53 \\
50 & Bruder J, 2011, Int J Entrep Behav R & Financial Constraints Of Ethnic Entrepreneurship: Evidence From Germany &   2 & 0.20 &  19 & 1.90 \\
51 & Buttner Eh, 1988, J Bus Venturing & Bank Loan Officers Perceptions Of The Characteristics Of Men, Women, And Successful Entrepreneurs &   9 & 0.27 & 103 & 3.12 \\
52 & Cabeza-Garcia L, 2019, Women Stud Int Forum & Female Financial Inclusion And Its Impacts On Inclusive Economic Development &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
53 & Calcagnini G, 2015, Ital Econ J & Gender Differences In Bank Loan Access: An Empirical Analysis &   0 & 0.00 &   5 & 0.83 \\
54 & Campello M, 2012, Rev Financ & Access To Liquidity And Corporate Investment In Europe During The Financial Crisis &   0 & 0.00 &  37 & 4.11 \\
55 & Canton E, 2013, Small Bus Econ & Perceived Credit Constraints In The European Union &   4 & 0.50 &  32 & 4.00 \\
56 & Cao Ntk, 2019, Asian Econ J & What Factors Determine Whether Small And Medium Enterprises Obtain Credit From The Formal Credit Market? The Case Of Vietnam &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
57 & Carter S, 2015, Int Small Bus J & Barriers To Ethnic Minority And Women's Enterprise: Existing Evidence, Policy Tensions And Unsettled Questions &   0 & 0.00 &  64 & 10.67 \\
58 & Cesaroni Fm, 2015, Proc Eur Conf Entrep & Access To Bank Credit During The Economic Crisis: A Comparison Between Italian Male And Female Entrepreneurs &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
59 & Chai Sj, 2019, Asia Pac J Manag & Social Networks And Informal Financial Inclusion In China &   1 & 0.50 &   2 & 1.00 \\
60 & Chakravarty Sr, 2013, J Policy Model & Financial Inclusion In India: An Axiomatic Approach &   4 & 0.50 &  30 & 3.75 \\
61 & Chandio Aa, 2017, Cogent Econ Financ & Famers' Access To Credit: Does Collateral Matter Or Cash Flow Matter?Evidence From Sindh, Pakistan &   2 & 0.50 &   9 & 2.25 \\
62 & Chaudhuri K, 2012, Appl Econ & Credit Rationing In Rural Credit Markets Of India &   3 & 0.33 &   8 & 0.89 \\
63 & Chauvet L, 2017, World Dev & Financial Inclusion, Bank Concentration, And Firm Performance &   1 & 0.25 &  14 & 3.50 \\
64 & Chavan Al, 2009, Lect Notes Comput Sc & How Mobile Money Can Drive Financial Inclusion For Women At The Bottom Of The Pyramid (Bop) In Indian Urban Centers &   0 & 0.00 &   5 & 0.42 \\
65 & Chen Dq, 2016, Abacus & Social Trust And Bank Loan Financing: Evidence From China &   0 & 0.00 &  11 & 2.20 \\
66 & Chen Dy, 2017, Electron Commer Res & Gender Discrimination In Online Peer-To-Peer Credit Lending: Evidence From A Lending Platform In China &   0 & 0.00 &   9 & 2.25 \\
67 & Chen Hk, 2018, J Financ Stabil & The Effect Of The Political Connections Of Government Bank Ceos On Bank Performance During The Financial Crisis &   0 & 0.00 &   6 & 2.00 \\
68 & Chen Lh, 2008, Proceedings Of The 3rd International Conference On Product Innovation Management, Vols I And Ii & Study On Reasons For Internal Financing Preference Of Family Business In China &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
69 & Chen Yl, 2013, J Bank Financ & Greasing The Wheels Of Bank Lending: Evidence From Private Firms In China &   2 & 0.25 &  46 & 5.75 \\
70 & Chen Ys, 2014, J Financ Serv Res & The Benefits Of Political Connection: Evidence From Individual Bank-Loan Contracts &   3 & 0.43 &  26 & 3.71 \\
71 & Chen Zb, 2017, J Fam Econ Iss & Financial Inclusion In China: Use Of Credit &   1 & 0.25 &   2 & 0.50 \\
72 & Cheng Ej, 2014, China Agr Econ Rev & The Demand For Credit, Credit Rationing And The Role Of Microfinance Evidence From Poor Rural Counties Of China &   1 & 0.14 &   7 & 1.00 \\
73 & Chipfupa U, 2018, Agrekon & Explaining Smallholder Aspirations To Expand Irrigation Crop Production In Makhathini And Ndumo-B, Kwazulu-Natal, South Africa &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.33 \\
74 & Chu Lk, 2019, Econ Bull & Determinants Of Financial Inclusions: Comparing High, Middle, And Low-Income Countries &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
75 & Churchill Sa, 2020, Appl Econ & Financial Inclusion And Poverty: A Tale Of Forty-Five Thousand Households &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 1.00 \\
76 & Claessens S, 2008, J Financ Econ & Political Connections And Preferential Access To Finance: The Role Of Campaign Contributions &  25 & 1.92 & 442 & 34.00 \\
77 & Cloud C, 1993, Rev Black Polit Econ & What Do We Know About Racial-Discrimination In Mortgage Markets &   0 & 0.00 &  17 & 0.61 \\
78 & Coleman S, 2000, J Small Bus Manage & Access To Capital And Terms Of Credit: A Comparison Of Men- And Women-Owned Small Businesses &  22 & 1.05 & 201 & 9.57 \\
79 & Cornaggia J, 2013, J Financ Econ & Does Risk Management Matter? Evidence From The Us Agricultural Industry &   0 & 0.00 &  23 & 2.88 \\
80 & Cornille D, 2019, J Financ Stabil & Heterogeneous Effects Of Credit Constraints On Smes' Employment: Evidence From The European Sovereign Debt Crisis &   0 & 0.00 &   1 & 0.50 \\
81 & Corrado G, 2015, J Econ Geogr & The Geography Of Financial Inclusion Across Europe During The Global Crisis &   1 & 0.17 &  12 & 2.00 \\
82 & Corsi M, 2017, J Dev Stud & Gender Discrimination In Microfinance? Some Evidence From Uganda &   1 & 0.25 &   3 & 0.75 \\
83 & Cui Yj, 2017, J Interdiscip Math & Analysis On Determinants Of Rural Household Credit In China &   2 & 0.50 &   2 & 0.50 \\
84 & Cull R, 2015, J Corp Financ & Government Connections And Financial Constraints: Evidence From A Large Representative Sample Of Chinese Firms &   4 & 0.67 &  83 & 13.83 \\
85 & Cull R, 2019, Oxford B Econ Stat & Dual Credit Markets And Household Usage To Finance: Evidence From A Representative Chinese Household Survey &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
86 & Dadzie Kq, 2013, J Public Policy Mark & Inclusive Economic Development Programs And Consumers' Access To Credit In Emerging Market Economies: The Public Policy Role Of Marketing In Rural Bank Programs In Ghana &   0 & 0.00 &  18 & 2.25 \\
87 & Dang Hd, 2020, Agric Finance Rev & Determinants Of Credit Demand Of Farmers In Lam Dong, Vietnam A Comparison Of Machine Learning And Multinomial Logit &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
88 & Das T, 2019, Int J Soc Econ & Does Credit Access Lead To Expansion Of Income And Multidimensional Poverty? A Study Of Rural Assam &   1 & 0.50 &   3 & 1.50 \\
89 & Davutyan N, 2016, Emerg Mark Financ Tr & Determinants Of Saving-Borrowing Decisions And Financial Inclusion In A High Middle Income Country: The Turkish Case &   0 & 0.00 &   4 & 0.80 \\
90 & Dawood Tc, 2019, Econ Sociol & Does Financial Inclusion Alleviate Household Poverty? Empirical Evidence From Indonesia &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
91 & Dehingia N, 2019, Ssm-Popul Hlth & More Than Credit: Exploring Associations Between Microcredit Programs And Maternal And Reproductive Health Service Utilization In India &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
92 & Dennis Sa, 2005, J Bus Finan Account & Firm Size Dependence In The Determinants Of Bank Term Loan Maturity &   1 & 0.06 &  14 & 0.88 \\
93 & Desai Rm, 2011, Q J Polit Sci & The Costs Of Political Influence: Firm-Level Evidence From Developing Countries &   2 & 0.20 &  22 & 2.20 \\
94 & Digiuseppe M, 2016, Econ Polit-Oxford & Borrowed Time: Sovereign Finance, Regime Type, And Leader Survival &   0 & 0.00 &   9 & 1.80 \\
95 & Diniz E, 2012, Electron Commer R A & Triggers And Barriers To Financial Inclusion: The Use Of Ict-Based Branchless Banking In An Amazon County &   1 & 0.11 &  31 & 3.44 \\
96 & Distinguin I, 2016, World Dev & Can Informal Firms Hurt Registered Smes' Access To Credit? &   0 & 0.00 &  16 & 3.20 \\
97 & Domeher D, 2017, Int J Soc Econ & Micro Determinants Of The Extent Of Credit Rationing Amongst Smes In Ghana &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
98 & Domeher D, 2017, J Afr Bus & Inter-Sectoral Differences In The Sme Financing Gap: Evidence From Selected Sectors In Ghana &   0 & 0.00 &   9 & 2.25 \\
99 & Doss Cr, 2019, Fem Econ & Gendered Paths To Asset Accumulation? Markets, Savings, And Credit In Developing Countries &   0 & 0.00 &   0 & 0.00 \\
100 & Dossa Lh, 2008, Agr Hum Values & Socio-Economic Determinants Of Keeping Goats And Sheep By Rural People In Southern Benin &   0 & 0.00 &  14 & 1.08 \\
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```